# Including an embedded framework using a cross-project-reference: Header no such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to create a Cocoa framework by using a cross-project reference in Xcode.

I have 2 projects: one for the framework; one for the application that will use the framework.

This framework is **not** intended to be stored within the system; it is an embedded framework that lives within the application bundle.

I have successfully made the cross-project reference, marked the framework as being a dependency of my target, added a Copy Files build phase that puts the framework in Contents/Frameworks/ and added the framework to the linker phase (I checked the little "Target" checkbox; I've also done it manually by dragging the framework into the linker phase).

My framework's install directory is correctly set to @executable_path/../Frameworks.

However, when I try to build my app it:

a)  Correctly builds the framework first
b)  Correctly copies the framework
c)  Errors because it cannot find the master header file in my framework

I have verified that the header is there.  I can see it in the app product that is partially built.

`ls build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Frameworks/Cioccolata.framework/Headers/Cioccolata.h 
build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Frameworks/Cioccolata.framework/Headers/Cioccolata.h`

I have been able to successfully build the app by copying my framework into /Library/Frameworks (I can then delete it again after the successful build), but this is a workaround, I'm looking to find it out why Xcode doesn't find the framework's master header file without it being copied to a system directory.  Is copying it to the app bundle during the build not sufficient?

Here's the full build transcript if it's any help (it's just a Hello World app right now, so not much going on here):

`Build Cioccolata of project Cioccolata with configuration Debug`

`SymLink /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/Current A
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
/bin/ln -sf A /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/Current`

`SymLink /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Resources Versions/Current/Resources
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
/bin/ln -sf Versions/Current/Resources /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Resources`

`SymLink /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Headers Versions/Current/Headers
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
/bin/ln -sf Versions/Current/Headers /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Headers`

`SymLink /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Cioccolata Versions/Current/Cioccolata
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
/bin/ln -sf Versions/Current/Cioccolata /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Cioccolata`

`ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist Info.plist
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
builtin-infoPlistUtility Info.plist -expandbuildsettings -platform macosx -o /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist`

`CpHeader build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CWHelloWorld.h CWHelloWorld.h
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/CWHelloWorld.h /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Headers`

`CpHeader build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Cioccolata.h Cioccolata.h
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/Cioccolata.h /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Headers`

`CopyStringsFile /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
setenv ICONV /usr/bin/iconv
/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings --validate --inputencoding utf-8 --outputencoding UTF-16 English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings --outdir /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj`

`ProcessPCH /var/folders/Xy/Xy-bvnxtFpiYBQPED0dK1++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Cioccolata_Prefix-dololiigmwjzkgenggebqtpvbauu/Cioccolata_Prefix.pch.gch Cioccolata_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mfix-and-continue -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2 -iquote /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Cioccolata-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Cioccolata-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Cioccolata-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Cioccolata-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/include -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/DerivedSources -c /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/Cioccolata_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/Xy/Xy-bvnxtFpiYBQPED0dK1++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Cioccolata_Prefix-dololiigmwjzkgenggebqtpvbauu/Cioccolata_Prefix.pch.gch`

`CompileC build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Objects-normal/i386/CWHelloWorld.o /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/CWHelloWorld.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mfix-and-continue -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2 -iquote /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Cioccolata-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Cioccolata-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Cioccolata-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Cioccolata-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/include -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/DerivedSources -include /var/folders/Xy/Xy-bvnxtFpiYBQPED0dK1++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Cioccolata_Prefix-dololiigmwjzkgenggebqtpvbauu/Cioccolata_Prefix.pch -c /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/CWHelloWorld.m -o /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Objects-normal/i386/CWHelloWorld.o`

`Ld /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Cioccolata normal i386
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -L/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug -F/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug -filelist /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Cioccolata.build/Debug/Cioccolata.build/Objects-normal/i386/Cioccolata.LinkFileList -install_name @executable_path/../Frameworks/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Cioccolata -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -o /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework/Versions/A/Cioccolata`

`Touch /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata
/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework`

`Build CioccolataTest of project CioccolataTest with configuration Debug`

`ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Info.plist Info.plist
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest
builtin-infoPlistUtility Info.plist -expandbuildsettings -platform macosx -o /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Info.plist`

`PBXCp build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Frameworks/Cioccolata.framework /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest
/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/Cioccolata/build/Debug/Cioccolata.framework /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Frameworks`

`CopyStringsFile /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest
setenv ICONV /usr/bin/iconv
/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings --validate --inputencoding utf-8 --outputencoding UTF-16 English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings --outdir /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Resources/English.lproj`

`CompileC build/CioccolataTest.build/Debug/CioccolataTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o main.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mfix-and-continue -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2 -iquote /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/CioccolataTest.build/Debug/CioccolataTest.build/CioccolataTest-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/CioccolataTest.build/Debug/CioccolataTest.build/CioccolataTest-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/CioccolataTest.build/Debug/CioccolataTest.build/CioccolataTest-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/CioccolataTest.build/Debug/CioccolataTest.build/CioccolataTest-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/Debug -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/Debug/include -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/CioccolataTest.build/Debug/CioccolataTest.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/CioccolataTest.build/Debug/CioccolataTest.build/DerivedSources -include /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/prefix.pch -c /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/main.m -o /Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/build/CioccolataTest.build/Debug/CioccolataTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o`

`In file included from <command-line>:0:
/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/prefix.pch:13:35: error: Cioccolata/Cioccolata.h: No such file or directory
/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/main.m: In function 'main':
/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/main.m:13: error: 'CWHelloWorld' undeclared (first use in this function)
/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/main.m:13: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/main.m:13: error: for each function it appears in.)
/Users/chris/Projects/Mac/CioccolataTest/main.m:13: error: 'hello' undeclared (first use in this function)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your 'Framework Search Paths' build setting include the path to the framework?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what would that path be?  This is an embedded framework so I'm not sure how I'd define where it would be during the build phase. I've tried `$(SRCROOT)/**` in the "Framework Search Paths" setting but that didn't help. The path to the framework in the final product would be Contents/Frameworks/Cioccolata.framework, but that's in the end product (and it's a standard location).

Comment: I tried this in the 'Framework Search Paths' and it has worked: `$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)`. That produces that path: `build/Debug/CioccolataTest.webapp/Contents/Frameworks`. Does this look like crazy voodoo madness? I assumed Xcode would handle this for me since it know's it's a dependency.

Comment: It needs to be the path to the framework, probabaly the framework's build directory (it won't have been copied into the app bundle at this stage). I can't tell if '$(SRCROOT)/**' is correct because i don't know if the framework has the same $(SRCROOT) as the app. You could setup both targets to share the same build directory and then set framework search paths to include $(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR), for example

Comment: $(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH) looks a little weird - does it work if you do a 'Clean All' before building your app? If it does, then it's ok.

Comment: It sure does :) This project will be open source so I wanted to use something that will always resolve to a valid path for other users.

Comment: The search paths can be relative paths

Comment: Couldn't get this to work with my setup, but d11wtq's solutions worked flawlessly. No need for any shared build directories or stuff like that.

Answer (score 9):

I know this post is old now, but I'm working on another project and have just had the displeasure of setting up another cross-project reference for an embedded framework that must be built from a separate project before building this project.

I came up with a much more elegant fix (and probably the "correct" fix) this time, basically because what I did last time wasn't working (Xcode kept complaining that it couldn't find the framework's main header file).

The solution.  I've just tested it on a number of projects from scratch just to be sure...

1. Add the other (dependency) project to your main project by doing "Project -> Add to project"
2. Double click on your target that requires products from the other project.
3. In the general tab, add the required products as direct dependencies (top panel).  Close this settings panel.
4. Drag the product from the cross-project reference into the Link Binary with Libraries build phase of your target.
5. Add a new "Copy Files" build phase, selecting "Products" as the destination directory (!!!).  Rename this build phase to "Copy Cross-Project Products".
6. Drag your cross-project product(s) into this new build phase and make sure that it's the first build phase in your target.
7. Add one final "Copy Files" build phase to your target, selecting "Frameworks" as the destination.
8. Drag your cross-project product(s) into this new build phase.

While it looks long-winded, most of it is pretty normal and exactly what you'd do if the dependency target was in the same project.  The crucial first build phase however needs to copy the built products from the other project into the current project's build directory.

Obviously Xcode is smart enough to get the other project to perform the build, but not smart enough to think to look there when it starts compiling your sources that depend on it.

Comment: I can't express how thankful I am for eventually having stumbled upon this solution of yours. I'd been fighting with cross-project referenced frameworks for hours with no luck. Consider my upvote a horde of thousand (imaginary) upvotes, sir.

Comment: Thanks mate! I have three frameworks in this configuration that were failing to build. But the above resolved build issue when only adding one of the frameworks to the copy files build phase!