# mDNSResponder not compiling out of the box on Maverick

Tags: c, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks, core-foundation

this morning I downloaded the lastest mDNSResponder from the Apple [opensource repository](http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/mDNSResponder/). I opened the xCode project (mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX) and tried to compile, but few files are missing:

- `#include <CoreFoundation/CFXPCBridge.h>` in BonjourEvents.c is not found.
- `#include <dispatch/private.h>` in dns-sd.c is not found (but compiles with GCC, so I'm ok with that)
- other errors...

I am running Xcode 5.1 on OSx 10.9.2, with command line tool installed.

I am attaching the output of xcodebuild:

```
    $ xcodebuild
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: The directory /Users/kas/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX also contains the legacy project 'mDNSResponder.pbproj' - ignoring it and using 'mDNSResponder.xcodeproj'.

=== BUILD TARGET BonjourEvents OF PROJECT mDNSResponder WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Development) ===

Check dependencies

CompileC build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BonjourEvents.o BonjourEvents.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/adsada/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=129 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Werror -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -D__APPLE_USE_RFC_3542=1 -D_DNS_SD_LIBDISPATCH=1 -DAPPLE_OSX_mDNSResponder=1 -D__MigTypeCheck=1 -DmDNSResponderVersion=(Engineering\ Build) -D_LEGACY_NAT_TRAVERSAL_ -D_BUILDING_XCODE_PROJECT_=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/askdjkadj/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/BonjourEvents-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/sdaad/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/BonjourEvents-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/sadad/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/BonjourEvents-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/asdsad/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/BonjourEvents-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/asdd/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/asad/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/adssad/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/DerivedSources -W -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wshadow -F/Users/asdd/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build -DUSE_SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_PRIVATE_HEADERS -fwrapv -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/asd/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BonjourEvents.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/sad/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BonjourEvents.dia -c /Users/asd/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/BonjourEvents.c -o /Users/ads/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BonjourEvents.o
/Users/asd/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/BonjourEvents.c:19:10: fatal error: 'CoreFoundation/CFXPCBridge.h' file not found
#include <CoreFoundation/CFXPCBridge.h>
         ^
1 error generated.

2014-04-06 13:10:32.208 xcodebuild[3417:30b]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-5067/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/SpecificationTypes/BuiltInSpecifications/Compilers/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:76
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/asd/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BonjourEvents.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “BonjourEvents.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fbacb566c60 {NSFilePath=/Users/asd/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BonjourEvents.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbacb5364c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/ada/Downloads/mDNSResponder-544/mDNSMacOSX/build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BonjourEvents.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, void (^__strong)(NSString *__strong))
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbacb561070>{name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/mDNSResponder.build/Development/BonjourEvents.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BonjourEvents.o BonjourEvents.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

and indeed `locate CFXPCBridge.h` returns nothing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including an embedded framework using a cross-project-reference: Header no such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681646/including-an-embedded-framework-using-a-cross-project-reference-header-no-such)

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Just ran into the same problem trying to compile `pmtool`. My guess is that `CFXPCBridge` just isn't opensource... Apple may opensource some things that are based on BSD code, but that doesn't mean they have to opensource dependencies or even make it possible to compile. Alas. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯